# calling asp.net webservice

Tags: android

i am  calling a asp.net webservice in andorid emulator using ecilipse. i am able to  call simple hello world program but when i call any other method from the same service im not getting any data. i am gettind output as org.ksoap2.serilazation.soapobject only

I am retrieving data from database through that service. But unfortunately I am unable to get any sort of data.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Hi do you still need help? I have had this problem for a long time, but I have manged to creat some code so you can get anydata you want from the dotnet webservice :) !!

Answer (score 0):

There could be one reason that, ksoap API have separate mechanism to handle complex return type while sample Hello World program might have singular return type.

Please try to remain precise though your question is open ended.